# e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Backend Internal error: Exception during code generation

Tags: android, kotlin

At the execution of my android kotlin project on my emulator, I receive this error during the compilation of the project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(Kotlin) Backend Internal error: Exception during code generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52081383/kotlin-backend-internal-error-exception-during-code-generation)

Comment: what is "Anko".

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error was i taking my TabLayout's id from xml and just pasted the id in my code without apply any kind of property or calling any function on it.